# No wireless internet connection, only ethernet connection

Tags: drivers, wireless

I know this sounds like a driver issue at first and I thought that might be the case myself but I don't believe it is.
So my back story is I've been using Ubuntu 18.04 on this laptop for almost a year now and I have just moved and switched internet providers. With my previous ISP my wireless internet worked just fine and I haven't changed anything about my computer so here it goes. I just recently moved to a new place and set up my internet. I have wireless connections on my gaming console, TV and Phones but not my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop. I can get a connection with ethernet though. When I try to search for wireless connections my access point shows up and it asks for my password and tries to connect. while trying to connect it will ask me a second time for my password and continue to try and connect before just booting me back off and never connecting or sending an error message. I do not believe its a router or modem issue and it shouldn't be a driver issue because it worked just fine at my previous residence. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

WIFI modem technicolor: model DPC3216
WIFI router Spectrum Serial # A6A4H968C14290

all lights indicate internet is working and connection can be established via ethernet cable...

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong as well. I am still new to Linux

Comment: Sounds like an encryption mismatch. Do the working devices use WPA2 or (WPA, WEP, none) (All bad)? `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` will show you log messages which should help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, this command returned a lot of information and is definitely new to me. I am seeing the access point im trying to connect to with all the others that are in range. even my old access point stored from my last house. it did return the flag  no-mac-addr-change.conf which I think could be the problem. If so how would I go about fixing it. would it be my routers mac address or my laptops mac address? I'll do more research...

Comment: I could post the output of the command as well but it'll be a lot of info. would that be safe to do?

Comment: No. Posting an entire log (hundreds of lines) is known as "logvomit", and is discouraged. Read the logs yourself, a line at a time, our loud, and determine which lines are worth inclusion.